# read file in assembly x86 ia-32

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to read a file in assembly (x86, IA-32) and i found this example:

```
mov ebx,eax
mov al,0x3
mov edi,esp
mov ecx,edi
xor edx,edx
mov dh,0xff
mov dl,0xff
int 0x80
```

where in eax (first instruction) there is the return code of the open syscall.
There are 2 things that i haven't completely understood:

1. why doing `mov edi,esp` and then `mov ecx,edi` instead of doing directly `mov ecx,esp`?
2. why putting `0xff` and `0xff` inside the edx register? The read syscall expects`count` so in this case the file size.

EDIT (complete code):

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    ;read the file
    jmp short call_rw

rw:
    push 0x5
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    xor ecx,ecx
    int 0x80
    mov ebx,eax
    mov al,0x3
    mov edi,esp
    mov ecx,edi
    xor edx,edx
    mov dl,0xff
    mov dh,0xff
    int 0x80
    mov edx,eax
    push 0x4
    pop eax
    mov bl, 0x1
    int 0x80
    push 0x1
    pop eax
    inc ebx
    int 0x80

call_rw:
    call rw
    message db "/home/user/file.txt"
```

Comment: You haven't specified your target OS, but I'm guessing Linux(?).

Comment: i'm sorry! Yes Linux (Gentoo x86)

Comment: @JerryCoffin my fault, i clicked too quickly on answer xD i updated my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I can see a couple of fairly obvious possibilities, but the question doesn't contain enough information to be sure which is likely to be accurate.

The first possibility would be that the size in `edi` gets used for some other purpose later in the code, so the move to `edi` has accomplished something useful, but we can't see exactly what here, because we can't see that other code that uses it.

The other obviously possibility would be that it's simply a mistake.

There are a few less obvious possibilities, such as the `mov ecx, edi` being used as an entry point from some other code, so if you start from the beginning of this code, it uses the value from `esp`, but there's other code that loads some other value into `edi` then jumps to the `mov ecx, edi`, thus using a different value instead of what's in `esp`.

There are some other possibilities as well, such as somebody basically inserting the equivalent of some NOPs to (for example) get some part of the code aligned to some boundary, but without as many lines of distraction as if they'd written `NOP` (say) 5 times.

For your second question, 0xffff in `edx` basically means it'll read up to 65535 bytes from the file. Most likely they allocated a 65535-byte buffer, so they don't want to read any more than that in a single call.

Edit (after complete code was added to question). Okay, now that we can see the complete code, we can start with the fact that the code is (to be as nice about it as possible) quite unconventionally written<sup>1</sup>.

He starts by jumping to `call_rw`, then (obviously enough) `call`ing `rw` from there. This pushes the address immediately *after* `call_rw` onto the stack. Then at `rw`, he pops that return value off the stack into `ebx`. This loads the address of `message` into `ebx`, then uses it as a parameter in the next system call (function 5, which opens a file, expecting `ebx` to contain a pointer to the name of the file).

Offhand, I'd just about have to guess that the code is either a deliberate (but fairly ineffective) attempt at obfuscation, or else the result of a compiler that internally produces some sort of stack-oriented internal code, then does a really lousy job of translating that to register-oriented object code. Or perhaps my first impression (see footnote below) was correct.

After removing the cruft, the first couple of sys-calls work out to something on this general order:

```
; open the file
mov eax, 5
mov ebx, offset filename
xor ecx, ecx
int 0x80

; read the file
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, 3
mov ecx, esp
mov edx, 0xffff
int 0x80
```

Sorry, but I'm too lazy to sort out all the rest. At first glance, it looks like it goes into an infinite loop (the code before `call_rw` flows into `call_rw`, calling `rw` again). Some of its gymnastics may prevent that from actually happening, but without a convincing argument for the need to do so, I lack the motivation to sort out more of this particular mess.

---

1. I'm working *really* hard at being diplomatic here. Before revision, this referred to the author as "a certifiable psychotic."